# How do I convert this spice code into a circuit of components?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis

I am looking for a piece of software which can take this spice code and convert it into a circuit of components.

The code is here:

```
1   .subckt memdiode + − H
2   *created by E.Miranda, F. Aguirre and J.Suñé, revised January 2022
3   .params
4   + H0 = 0 ri = 50 RPP = 1E10
5   + etas = 50 vs = 1.4
6   + etar = 100 vr = −0.4
7   + ion = 1E-2 aon = 2 ron = 10
8   + ioff = 1E-7 aoff = 2 roff = 10
9   + vt = 0.4 isb = 2E-4 gam = 1; isb = 1/gam = 0 no SB/SF
10  *Memory Equation
11  BI 0 H I = if(V(+,-)> = 0, (1-V(H))/TS(V(C,-)),-V(H)/TR(V(C,-)))
12  CH H 0 1 ic = {H0}
13  *I-V
14  RI + C {ri}
15  RS C B R = K(ron,roff)
16  BF B - I = K(ion,ioff)*sinh(K(aon,aoff)*V(B,-))
17  RB + - {RPP}
18  *Auxiliary functions
19  .func K(on,off) = off+(on-off)*limit(0,1,V(H))
20  .func TS(x) = exp(-etas*(x- if(I(BF)>isb,vt,vs)))
21  .func TR(x) = exp(etar* if(gam = = 0,1,pow(limit(0,1,V(H)),gam))*(x-vr))
22  .ends
```

Comment: LTspice? Pspice?

Comment: If this is the only reason you want that, then just do it by hand. There's nothing much there. Only a few components. If you want general purpose software for the future, then I'm sure someone's attempted it. But it's not easy if the resulting diagram should be drawn out in human-readable form. (Easy, if you don't care about a rat's nest with wires crossing over part symbols.)

Comment: I have no idea how I would turn this into an equivalent circuit

Comment: @ABC123 Read [Appendix 3 at this very famous document](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1975/ERL-m-520.pdf). The syntax is explained. Keep in mind this was back in the day when ASCII was only just coming into common usage, there were essentially no graphics terminals or displays (PLATO produced the first one I ever got to use), and complicated parsing wasn't desired. So the syntax is simple and completely notepad'able. It's not hard to learn. "R" is for resistor, "C" is for capacitor, and like that. How hard can it be? Now, if you are expecting someone else to do your chores ...

Comment: @periblepsis what about functions, how would this be implemented a a component?

Comment: @ABC123 They aren't. They are added as "cards" on the schematic. (These are the so-called "dot-cards.") Back in the 1970's when there were no graphics available, they actually were just another card in the deck. Trivial. Decades later, Spice programs offered graphics, things got more complicated, and programmers had to figure out a way. Different Spice programs will have different ways of doing that. But there will always be a way. In LTspice, for example you just hit "S" while on the schematic and a dialog box pops up. Just type the exact text into it and then place it onto the schematic.

Comment: how would i turn this function into a circuit afterwards? for example if i have a card that says x^2+1 how could i turn this into a circuit?

Comment: @ABC123 A mathematical function that takes `x` and returns `x^2+1` is just that. It's not and never will be a circuit. If you want a circuit that performs that kind of function, you'll have to design it. Spice programs don't do electronic circuit design given a formula. For one thing, the formula doesn't say if it is a voltage input and voltage output, or a current input and a voltage output, etc. But there are other better reasons why Spice programs don't do any of that for you.

Comment: I'm just repeating the same information here but trying to make it more concise.  You have only 5 components there, so it should be trivial by hand. One capacitor (C), three resistors (R), and two current B-sources (use LTspice `bi` symbol for this if using LTspice). The `.func` lines can be copy-pasted as a SPICE directive (press `S` key). The `.params` can also be pasted as a SPICE directive. The `+` symbol just tells the SPICE software to continue the previous line but allows you to format vertically for readability. So you really just have 5 components and a few SPICE directives.